# Parsing command line arguments for string/integer to stdout

Tags: c, command-line-arguments, atoi

Programs can be called with command line arguments. For example, a program printargs might be called as ./printargs -a2 -b4.

I want to implement a program that accepts two arguments -aA and -bB for integers A and B in arbitrary order, i.e. -aA -bB and -bB -aA are both legitimate arguments when calling your program and converts A and B to integers, and writes to stdout/terminal the line “A is (INSERT A) and B is (INSERT B)”.

For example calling

printargs -a2 -b4
or

printargs -b4 -a2
should output

A is 2 and B is 4

I have made some progress I think and I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char *argv[])
{


int a,b;

a = atoi(argv[0]);
b = atoi(argv[1]);

printf("A is  %d and B is %d\n",a,b);

return 0;

}
```

I get the output in the Terminal - which is of course incorrect.

```
A is  0 and B is 0
```

when running the code/command

```
./print -a2 -b4
```

in the terminal

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't care about `-a` or `-b` in your program. Without handling these, `atoi` will never be able to convert the numbers. You might take a look at `getopt` for parsing command line arguments. Also: `argv[0]` does not contain what you think it does. Besides that: You should never access `argv` without checking for correct number of arguments first.

Comment: it is the first time i use C. Can you be more specific How i can proceed? Thanks.

Comment: Check the manual for `getopt` and check if that function is available for you. This function helps with parsing the parameters.

Comment: You want to add the parameters in any random order. Therefore you must first verify if an argument starts with `-a` or `-b` or anything else. Otherwise how would you know if the value is for `a` or `b`? You seem to assume that there is some kind of automatic relation between argumen `-a<x>` and variable `a` in your code. That relation does not exist.

Comment: [`getopt()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) is nice and good.... but it may be a bit too much for OP, @Gerhardh :)

Comment: i really don't get it i am sorry

Comment: how can i write that?

Comment: `int A;
int B;
for (int j =1; j<argc; ++j){
sscanf (argv[j], "-a%d", &A);
sscanf (argv[j], "-b%d", &B);
}`

Comment: why is argc=3? isn't it 4?

Comment: the output differs when i switch place of `./print -a2 -b4` :/

Comment: `int a;
int b;

for (int j =1; j<argc; ++j)

{
sscanf (argv[j], "-a%d", &a);
sscanf (argv[j], "-b%d", &b);
}

a = atoi(argv[1] +2);
b = atoi(argv[2] +2);


printf("A is  %d and B is %d\n",a,b);

return 0;

}

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sscanf` can be used to parse the arguments.
Check that `argc` is 3.
This will work with `./printargs -a3 -b45` or `./printargs -b45 -a3`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int j = 0;

    if ( argc != 3) {
        fprintf ( stderr, "Useage;\n\t%s -ax -by\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    for ( j = 1; j < argc; ++j) {
        sscanf ( argv[j], "-a%d", &a);
        sscanf ( argv[j], "-b%d", &b);
    }

    printf ( "A is  %d and B is %d\n", a, b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but should we not take use of the function `atoi()` to convert to integer?

Comment: fucking fantastic. I understand it now. Thank you A LOT! <3

Answer (score 2):

When you do

```
$ ./print -a2 -b4
```

you have

```
argc == 3
argv[0] ==> "./print"
argv[1] ==> "-a2"
argv[2] ==> "-b4"
argv[3] == NULL
```

---

To convert `"-a2"` to the integer `2` you need to ignore the first 2 characters.

```
int a = atoi("-a2" + 2); // same as atoi("2")
```

---

Of course, in your case, you need to identify the `'a'` or `'b`' (and possibly the `'-'`) in the arguments...

Comment: don't really get it i am sorry :/

Comment: What would you expect `atoi("twenty")` to give?

Comment: Just one value... of type `int`. That (`0`) is probably correct (though it means *error*). What would you expect `atoi("-b42")` to give?

Comment: @GAUSS Use `strncmp` or `strstr` to check if an argument starts with `"-a"` or `"-b"` to identify which argument provides which parameter. Then extract the number while skipping the first 2 characters.

Comment: pmg: i understand that it depend on how you print it with? like %d or %s. I am totally beginner. Sorry

Comment: Not quite... the initial part of `-b42` cannot be converted to an integer, so `atoi` gives `0` indicating error. To pass a valid integer to `atoi` you need to advance to the first digit... `atoi("-b42" + 2)` ... because `"-b42" + 2` points to `"42"` and `atoi("42")` gives the expected value.

Comment: int a;
int b;
a = atoi("-a2" +2);
b = atoi("-b4" +2);
printf("A is  %d and B is %d\n",a,b);

gives : A is  2 and B is 4

Comment: Half way there. Now replace the constant string with the proper `argv[]`

Comment: do you mean like this?

`a = atoi(argv[] +2); `

Comment: `a = atoi(argv[1] + 2);`

Answer (score 0):

From the C Standard (5.1.2.2.1 Program startup, p.#2)

> — **If the value of argc is greater than zero, the string pointed to by
> argv[0] represents the program name**; argv[0][0] shall be the null
> character if the program name is not available from the host
> environment. I**f the value of argc is greater than one, the strings
> pointed to by argv[1] through argv[argc-1] represent the program
> parameters.**

That is if you specified arguments -aA and -bB then they are will stored in `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` in the order in which they are specified when the program is launched. In this case `argc` will be equal to `3`.

Thus these statements

```
a = atoi(argv[0]);
b = atoi(argv[1]);
```

But even if you will write like

```
a = atoi(argv[1]);
b = atoi(argv[2]);
```

nevertheless again this statement will be incorrect because you need to use an offset to skip prefixes `-a` or `-b`.

And as you wrote yourself the parameters can be specified in any order.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) 
{
    enum { N = 3 };
    const char prefix[][N] = { "-a", "-b" };
    
    int valid = argc == 3;
    
    if ( valid )
    {
        valid = ( memcmp( argv[1], prefix[0], N - 1 ) == 0   && 
                  memcmp( argv[2], prefix[1], N - 1 ) == 0 ) ||
                ( memcmp( argv[1], prefix[1], N - 1 ) == 0   &&
                  memcmp( argv[2], prefix[0], N - 1 ) == 0 );
    }
    
    if ( !valid )
    {
        fputs( "Invalid format of the command line.\n", stderr );
        fprintf ( stderr, "Usage\t%s -aA -bB\n", argv[0] );
        fprintf ( stderr, "   or\t%s -bB -aA\n", argv[0] );
        
        return 0;
    }
    
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    
    if ( memcmp( argv[1], prefix[0], N - 1 ) == 0 )
    {
        a = atoi( argv[1] + N - 1 );
        b = atoi( argv[2] + N - 1 );
    }
    else
    {
        a = atoi( argv[2] + N - 1 );
        b = atoi( argv[1] + N - 1 );
    }
    
    printf("A is %d and B is %d\n", a, b );
    
    return 0;
}
```